# How to add both rows and columns to a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a null bootstrap in R. The dataset has four species and associated sample values. I want to calculate the `mean` and a special `poisson` function, sampling 5 values at a time from the distribution associated with each species. Here is my attempt at the code. I sampled 5 and tried to use summarise to calculate the mean and poisson function from those five values. I get an error that says `! New rows can't add columns.` Any suggestions on how to correct this to get the desrired output (attached).

```
set.seed(111)
library(truncnorm)
sample <- rtruncnorm(n = 1440,a = 0,b = 10,mean = 5,sd = 2)
sp <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 360)

df <- data.frame(sample, sp)

output <- tibble(mean.set = numeric(), 
                 poisson.set = numeric(), 
                 sp = character(),
                 set = numeric()

set.seed(42)                    
for(i in 1:1440){
  samp1 <- df %>% filter(sp == 'A') %>% sample_n(5, replace = TRUE) %>% summarise(mean.set = mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE), possion.set = ((var(sample, na.rm=TRUE)/ mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)^2) - (1/mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)))) %>% mutate(set = i)
  samp2 <- df %>% filter(sp == 'B') %>% sample_n(5, replace = TRUE) %>% summarise(mean.set = mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE), possion.set = ((var(sample, na.rm=TRUE)/ mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)^2) - (1/mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE))))%>% mutate(set = i)
  samp3 <- df %>% filter(sp == 'C') %>% sample_n(5, replace = TRUE) %>% summarise(mean.set = mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE), possion.set = ((var(sample, na.rm=TRUE)/ mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)^2) - (1/mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE))))%>% mutate(set = i)
  samp4 <- df %>% filter(sp == 'D') %>% sample_n(5, replace = TRUE) %>% summarise(mean.set = mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE), possion.set = ((var(sample, na.rm=TRUE)/ mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)^2) - (1/mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE))))%>% mutate(set = i)
  output %>% add_row(bind_rows(samp1, samp2, samp3, samp4))  -> output
}


Error:
! New rows can't add columns.
✖ Can't find columns `possion.set` and `set` in `.data`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred

#Expected output
 set mean.set poisson.set sp
  1    5          2        A
  2    4          9        A
  ....
  48   12          0        A 
  1    5          2        B
  2    4          9        B
  ....
  48   22          0        B  
   .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with error is based on the difference in column name in 'output' i.e. `poisson.set` and in the for loop `possion.set`.  By correcting either one of them, it works (In addition, `sp` was not created in the `summarise` resulting in `NA`)

```
output <- tibble(mean.set = numeric(), 
+                  possion.set = numeric(), 
+                  sp = character(),
+                  set = numeric()
+ 
+ )
> set.seed(42)                    
> for(i in 1:1440){
+   samp1 <- df %>% filter(sp == 'A') %>% sample_n(5, replace = TRUE) %>% summarise(sp = "A", mean.set = mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE), possion.set = ((var(sample, na.rm=TRUE)/ mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)^2) - (1/mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)))) %>% mutate(set = i)
+   samp2 <- df %>% filter(sp == 'B') %>% sample_n(5, replace = TRUE) %>% summarise(sp = "B", mean.set = mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE), possion.set = ((var(sample, na.rm=TRUE)/ mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)^2) - (1/mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE))))%>% mutate(set = i)
+   samp3 <- df %>% filter(sp == 'C') %>% sample_n(5, replace = TRUE) %>% summarise(sp = "C", mean.set = mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE), possion.set = ((var(sample, na.rm=TRUE)/ mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)^2) - (1/mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE))))%>% mutate(set = i)
+   samp4 <- df %>% filter(sp == 'D') %>% sample_n(5, replace = TRUE) %>% summarise(sp = "D", mean.set = mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE), possion.set = ((var(sample, na.rm=TRUE)/ mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)^2) - (1/mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE))))%>% mutate(set = i)
+   output %>% add_row(bind_rows(samp1, B = samp2,samp3, samp4))  -> output
+ }
```

---

In addition, we could do this without a `for` loop as well, i.e. `group_by` the 'sp' column and use `replicate/rerun` for multiple iterations

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
output2 <- rerun(1440, df %>%
           group_by(sp) %>%
           slice_sample(n = 5, replace = TRUE) %>% 
           summarise(mean.set = mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE), 
           possion.set = ((var(sample, na.rm=TRUE)/ 
     mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE)^2) - (1/mean(sample, na.rm=TRUE))))) %>% 
    bind_rows(.id = 'set')
```